# Changing Method called without new instance of Python Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm new to Python OOP and for the purpose of this question I have simplified my problem to this:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def add(self):
        # some arbitrary change
        return self.a + self.b

    def subtract(self):
        # some arbitrary change
        return self.a - self.b


a = Foo(a=1, b=2).add()
b = Foo(a=1, b=3).subtract()
```

So I have an object, which has 2 methods which do different things, in order for me to get some output, I have created 2 separate instances of `Foo` as the value `b` has changed.

Is there a way for me to just dynamically set `b` and the `obj.method()` without just listing them one after the other? I.E: some sort of generic class that I can use to dynamically set the attributes and the methods that are present in the object? or is there anything built in I can use...

## Edit

#### Here is another example:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = list(a)
        self.b = list(b)

    def method1(self):.
        # some arbitrary change in data
        return self.a * 2

    def method2(self):
        return self.b + [5, 6, 4]


a = Foo(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[]).method1()
b = Foo(b=[1, 2, 3], a=[]).method2()

print(a)
print(b)
```

So here, the input list changes based on the method called, is there a way for me to package this up so I could feed just one instance some data and then it 'knows' that list `a` is for `method1()`, list `b` is for `method2()` - I want to use the word `reflection` but I feel like that might not be accurate.

Again I'm new to OOP so any advice is appreciated

Comment: why not just set it with `a.b = 3`? Your question seems too abstract to suggest an answer

Comment: What I'm asking is, is there a way to infer the methods of an object and then use that inference to execute the method. From reading the `getattr()` might be what I'm looking for

Comment: This can't really be answered without more information about how you plan to use `Foo`. My first suggestion would be that `b` shouldn't be an instance attribute, but an argument to the methods. `f = Foo(a=1); a = f.add(2); b = f.substract(3)`.

Comment: aww okay that makes sense

Comment: I'd have thought the same as above but then you're just writing a wrapper around an integer which does mathematical operations pretty well already

Comment: Yeah, the simplified calculator was probs a bad example, currently working on something that shows my problem clearer...

Comment: Are you looking for mutually exclusive parameters? I.e just call `method` which does `return self.method1() if self.a else self.method2()`, otherwise inheritance and seperate classes probably makes more sense

Comment: `method1()` and `method2()` will always have to be called, but I wanted them in one object instance, where 1 attribute in the instances changes (`a`, `b`)

Comment: Is there any reason why you use a class for this? There isn't any point to the class'  state, other than providing the arguments to the methods. You could just as well provide the arguments directly, e.g. ``def add(a, b): return a + b`` (similar for other methods) and remove the class entirely. It's not sensible to recommend a means how to do something you should not do in the first place.

Comment: The first thing to learn about OOP is when it's appropriate to use: that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo:
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def subtract(self, a, b):
        return a - b

fo = Foo()

a = fo.add(1,2)
b = fo.subtract(1,3)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need 2 instances of `Foo` to achieve this.
Just do something like this:

```
foo = Foo(a = 1, b = 2)
# Perform addition (now 'a' is 1 and 'b' is 2)
a = foo.add()
# Change 'b'
foo.b = 3
# Now perform subtraction (now 'a' is 1 and 'b' is 3)
b = foo.subtract()
```